# PHP str_replace not replacing entire string?

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, quotations

I've been working on a very large, complicated framework I'm writing. I have used a process similar to this one for two other packages, and it worked flawlessly, however this `str_replace` is giving me trouble.

This is a small snippet from a much larger function. The function this particular snippet is from replaces the default value in a config file to a value dependent on user input. I'm not going to include all the other various string replacements that go on in this function, nor am I going to detail the script which grabs the contents of the config file and writes it. The issue is isolated to this snippet. I know so because this snippet replicates the issue in the larger function when it is isolated in a test file.

The equivilent code is...

```
<?php
$new_table_array = '$ecom_tables = [
          "product" => "test1",
          "promo" => "test2",
          "records" => "test3"
        ];';
$test = str_replace("$ecom_tables = [];", $new_table_array, '
  $ecom_tables = [];
');
?>
```

That snippet is formatted identically to the real function. The result of this snippet in the function, and in the test file is...

```
  $ecom_tables$ecom_tables = [
          "product" => "test1",
          "promo" => "test2",
          "records" => "test3"
        ];
```

I have looked over my concatenations, and insured that all of my string quotations are in the correct place. It passes the syntax check, and also runs when I load the test page, however the result is always unexpected.

Why is `str_replace` only replacing part of the string I specified with the new value?

Comment: Probably your use of double quotes `"$ecom_tables = [];",` meaning that the value of `$ecom_tables` will be evaluated as your from string - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @MarkBaker, you were correct. I'm confused as to why this is happening. Using double quotes should define a string literal in this case shouldn't it?

Comment: No, read the page that I linked from the docs..... using double quotes will try to interpret any PHP variables.... this is an absolute fundamental of PHP, and you'd be well advised to understand it.... if you want to use double quotes, then you need to escape characters like `$` if you want a literal `"\$ecom_tables = [];"`